# How to test a collection class with PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a class similar to this (some logic removed for brevity):

```
class FooCollection {
    protected $_foos;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_foos = new SplObjectStorage();
    }

    public function addFoo(FooInterface $foo) {
        $this->_foos->attach($foo);
    }

    public function removeFoo(FooInterface $foo) {
        $this->_foos->detach($foo);
    }
}
```

I'd like to test the `addFoo()` and `removeFoo()` methods using PHPUnit, and I was wondering what the best strategy would be to do this?  As far as I can tell, I have only a few options:

1. Add a method `hasFoo(FooInterface $foo)` and check this after the add.
2. Add a method `getFoos()` that directly returns the `SplObjectStorage` instance and check if `$foo` is in it after the add.
3. Try to `removeFoo($foo)` after `addFoo($foo)` and check for an exception.
4. Make `$_foos` a public property and check it directly after the add (bad, bad, bad...).

Options #1 and #2 are changing the public interface solely for testing purposes, and I'm not sure how I feel about that.  They seem like pretty generic, useful methods to have anyway on the surface, but in my particular case, I never have a need to check for the existance of a particular `Foo` instance in the collection, nor retrieve all of the instances, so it really would just be bloat.  Also, it seems like if I'm testing multiple parts of the interface in one test, I'm not really testing a "unit," but that's more or less just a philosophical hangup.

Option #3 seems awkward to me.

Option #4 is a really bad idea, and I shouldn't have even listed it, as I wouldn't do it even if it were suggested here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that collection class has something which returns the items in the collection. Otherwise the class would be pretty useless. And no don't change your code to be able to test it (unless you screwed up you design in other ways which prevent you from testing it)

Comment: @PeeHaa: It does not contain any methods for retrieving items from it (as there is no need to do so).  It does contain methods for *operating* on the collection (which I have omitted since they're not relevant), though, and that's why it's not a "useless" class.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but in my defense you may want to give your class a better name in that case ;)

Answer (score 5):

Why not create a mock `SplObjectStorage` object that you pass in to the constructor?  Then you can assert that the `attach` and `detach` methods are called on the mock.

```
function testAttachFOO() {
    $mockStorage = $this->getMockBuilder('SplObjectStorage')
                    ->setMethods(array('attach'))
                    ->getMock();

    $mockFoo = $this->getMock('FooInterface');

    $mockStorage->expects($this->once())
        ->method('attach')
        ->with($mockFoo);

    $collection = new FooCollection($mockStorage);

    $collection->addFoo($mockFoo);
}
```

And something similar for `removeFoo`.

Doing this does require that you change the constructor so that you can inject the dependency.  But IMO this makes the code clearer as to what is going on.  Also makes testing things easier.

So the constructor becomes:

```
public function __construct(SPLObjectStorage $storage) {
    $this->_foos = $storage;
}
```

If the class becomes difficult to build doing this, it is a sign that the class is doing too much and should be refactored into more, smaller classes.

Comment: Can you demonstrate some assertions which you would use in this example?

Comment: Based on the code that you have, there are no additional assertions.  My example test has two.  `expects()` and `with()` are assertions that something happens with the mock.  I am asserting that the method gets called only once and asserting that the method call is made with a particular parameter.

Comment: +1: This is all very correctly said including naming the smell having `new` inside the `__construct()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post a public accessor for getting the collection, but I am sure you have one, otherwise adding/removing foos to an array which is publically inaccessible makes no sense. So you could try something like (phpunit 3.6, php 5.4):

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->NumbersCollection = new NumbersCollection;
}

public function tearDown()
{
    unset($this->NumbersCollection);
}

public function testNumbersCollection()
{
    $this->NumbersCollection->addNumber(1);
    $this->NumbersCollection->addNumber(2);

    $this->assertSame(3, $this->NumbersCollection->sum());
    $this->assertSame(2, $this->NumbersCollection->product());

    $this->NumbersCollection->removeNumber(1);

    $this->NumbersCollection->addNumber(7);

    $this->assertSame(9, $this->NumbersCollection->sum());
    $this->assertSame(14, $this->NumbersCollection->product());
}
```

Comment: There are other methods which operate on the collection (which I left out for brevity), but there is nothing that retrieves the objects, as there is never a need to pull them back out again (except for testing, which I noted in my question).  The function of the class is to accept objects, and perform certain operations on them as a collection.

Comment: Right, but don't you return the collection at some point? Why write logic affecting objects in the collection, but never return them or use them?

Comment: The collection's methods perform operations on the items and return results, but there is no need to return the items themselves.  Sorry that I can't give a better explanation of the details (NDA).  Maybe it would help explain better if you consider a collection of numbers: `$numbers = new NumbersCollection(); $numbers->addNumber(1); $numbers->addNumber(2); $sum = $numbers->sum(); $product = $numbers->product();` and so on.  It's not a worthless class, I promise.  :-)

Comment: I had considered something like this, but it occurs to me that if `testNumbersCollection()` fails, it's not indicative of whether the problem was with `addNumber()` or `sum()`.  So it's definitely a test, but not necessarily a "unit test", since it's testing 2 different "units" or facets of the interface at the same time.  I'll probably end up going with this strategy anyway, but that was my original hang-up.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ya the only way you could test addNumber outside of the method would be to check the source array, which prompted my initial response. But with the above unit test, if you add a number and then sum or product and the assertion fails, you could add a debug flag to output the source array to a log file or something.

Comment: What did you end up going with?